# New tab is not showing image in IE?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, base64

I have a View where I show image links that will open in a new window. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE the image is not showing. Here is my cshtml code:

```cshtml
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ImagesByteses.Count; i++)
{
    <a href="#">
        <img id="img @i" class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImagesByteses[i]))" onclick="window.open('data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImagesByteses[i]))', '_blank')" alt="" />
    </a>
}
```

The code is running fine in Firefox and Chrome but in IE new window open but image is not showing. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not allow navigation *to* data-URIs. This is a security measure that has been put in place to prevent [certain spoofing attacks](http://klevjers.com/papers/phishing.pdf).

Instead you could open the new window, and pass the data-URI to it, perhaps using [`.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Browser_compatibility).